# Why my stroke goes when I fill a color using eye-dropper tool in adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector, shapes

I am very new to adobe illustrator and I am trying to fill some colors on my drawn shapes.

But the only problem I am facing is whenever I am trying to fill color to any object using the **eyedropper (I) tool**

the stroke disappears automatically.
Please see the video attached below.

[image: video]

Is there any way to deal with it?

Comment: Well obviously somebody might also want to copy the appearence of strokes with eyedropper too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the eyedropper to copy *appearance*. Your source shape has a fill but no stroke. You're copying the whole appearance, so when you apply to the destination object it will have the same attributes - a fill with no stroke.

Just apply the stroke to the source object, when you use the eyedropper it will copy both fill and stroke, then apply it to the destination object.

Or change the preferences as @Scott suggested in his answer  - I'd only do that if it's something that you want constantly.

Answer (score 5):

**Double-click** the **Eyedropper tool** in the **toolbar** and select what you want it to pickup and apply.

[image]

Ideally, one uses the **Swatch Panel** in Illustrator and merely clicks the swatch you want to use for the fill (with the fill active on the Color Panel).

It's just application differences.. the eyedropper is more useful in Photoshop, and swatches are more useful in Illustrator.

Answer (score 2):

The eyedropper tool duplicates the **complete** style of the source object, aka appearance, aka **fill AND stroke**, from the blue(ish) box, to your shape.

If you need your shape to have the lines in blue, you need to **add that color as a swatch**, and **apply** the blue swatch to the stroke of your shape.

Looks like this could be **helpful**: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/painting-fills-strokes.html

Answer (score 2):

Click and hold shift while applying color with color picker! And one more thing, Your stroke will be active while applying!